# Change from local to external host

Tags: database, distributed-database, yugabytedb

I am running yugabyte using yb-ctl create. I am using --rf 3 to create a 3 node cluster. How can make it listen on the external IP address instead of localhost? And run on three different IPs?

Answer (score 1):

yb-ctl only works for local deployments for quick debugging or testing. To bring up yugabyte on three separate hosts, you can follow the instructions at https://docs.yugabyte.com/latest/deploy/manual-deployment/. The commands there are for 4 different hosts but it should be very similar for 3 hosts.

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, `yb-ctl` is for local clusters on a single node and not meant to be used for multi-node deployments. In addition to the manual install option, there are a number of orchestrated multi-node deployment options available:

- Terraform on any cloud
- Cloud formation in AWS, Deployment manager in GCP and ARM templates in Azure
- If Kubernetes is of interest, thats another easy way to deploy using Operators or Helm charts.